# TYPO3 CMS versus TYPO3 Neos

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, neoscms

If you have to choose between TYPO3 CMS and TYPO3 Neos, which criteria are relevant to decide?

What are the main differences between those two variants (features, editing, performance, hosting, etc.)?

How different is the developing in terms of learning curve, complexity, programming speed?

Comment: Not really a fit for SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more.

Comment: @maryisdead: The on-topic page includes "software tools commonly used by programmers" and as a programmer I'd like to get some idea about the differences of developing with one or the other. What's wrong about that? What place would be better to ask for this?

Answer (score 10):

(disclaimer): I am part of the Neos team - so I cannot compare the differences clearly as I have not been working productively with TYPO3 CMS.

Still, I'd like to give some general remarks as well on the above points:

**Learning Curve**: I think Neos more consistent concept-wise than TYPO3 CMS -- because we were able to learn from the pros and cons of TYPO3 (as quite some of us have been TYPO3 CMS core devs in the past). On the other hand, while we try to have as much documentation as possible, we know that documentation is still a weak point of Neos. There definitely exists a lot more documentation for TYPO3 than for Neos, and the community is bigger.

**Complexity**: Hard to compare. I think both systems are complex in certain areas, easier in others.

**Speed**: If you download Neos, it is by default running in **Development** Context, which makes it slower, but nicer to work with during development. Many caches are automatically cleared then. However, **make sure to enable the Production context** when working with Flow/Neos applications. You can do that by adding an environment variable `FLOW_CONTEXT=Production` to your apache/php/nginx configuration. I've seen quite some productive instances running (slowly) in development context.

**Features**: I think that one is honestly hard to compare. As an example, TYPO3 CMS has a big "News" extension (actually, several of them); which might get you started easily on the one side, but on the other side adjusting it to very specific output can be more complex. In Neos, it is very easy to create your own node types and build them in a way that they do exactly what you want them to do. So for now, you will create a "News" node type which works the way you like. I think in the longer run, more best practices will emerge, leading to "de-facto" standard packages for solving e.g. News. As an example, there is the https://github.com/Flow-Community/Community.News package maintained by Neos community members.

**Important:** Neos 2.0 is currently in beta phase, containing e.g. more advanced access controls along with lots of other smaller and bigger features, as well as lots of bugfixes. If you can, I'd suggest you use this one.

**Verdict**: I know many of the TYPO3 CMS devs and they are also doing truly great things :-) So I won't give a recommendation for the one or the other.

Greets, 
Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

I wonder that the criteria of future development is not mentioned here. For me it's one of the most important, especially after [splitting](http://typo3.org/news/article/this-week-in-typo3-2015-week-25/) Neos and TYPO3 CMS just some month ago. TYPO3 CMS is well established over years. Neos is much younger, which brings perhaps advantages in some technical parts. [Some people](http://typo3.org/news/article/typo3-project-focuses-on-typo3-cms-neos-to-start-its-own-community/) fear the separation and hope that Neos can build a community and not ends as a death-system.

If you want to discover how it feels like for editors in backends the demo sites of [Neos](https://www.neos.io/features/demo.html) and [TYPO3 CMS](http://demo.typo3.org/) can give you an idea.

Comment: Hey,

now, more than 4 years after the split, Neos is very much alive. On slack.neos.io, we have a community of more than 1500 people; and we're releasing three bigger versions each year (+ lots of patch level releases).
In the last two years, we have switched the User Interface from Ember to React, making it more extensible and stable - and we're right now working on a new Content Repository basis :) 

All the best, Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 CMS is more advanced and enterprise-ready. 
This includes extensibility, existing features/extensions and community.

TYPO3 NEOS on the other hand has a very nice interface for administrating content - you can edit the content directly on the website and you have no separate backend.

**Regarding you points:**

learning curve:  quite the same. TYPO3 CMS has the bigger community so you may find more articles, snipptes...

complexity: see above

speed: at the moment TYPO3 CMS (version 7.1) has the way better performance. but they are improving neos pretty fast. at the moment I would recommend using Varnish if you decide for neos.. ;)

**main differences**

features: CMS a lot more

editing: NEOS way nicer

performance: see above (speed)

hosting: you need PHP 5.5/MySQL for both..  Varnish for neos recommended

**conclusion**

if you have a website with simple content only and not a complex rights management for administrating user, TYPO3 NEOS can be quite nice. Even they got a cool Framework underneath (TYPO3 FLOW).
Otherwise - go for CMS (TYPO3 CMS 7.1)

Comment: I replaced vagrant with Varnish because I'm pretty sure you meant Varnish.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the speed issues you're talking about. We have Neos 1.2 with ~120ms per request, CMS 6.2 using Varnish with about the same while CMS 6.2 without Varnish (e.g. website of your agency) has > 200ms. Is CMS 7.1 really so much faster? That would be great :-).

Comment: they removed a lot of compatibilty stuff in 7.1 since 6.2, the release manager of 7.1 (beni mack) said... I read an article where they stated that in their AB tests with TYPO3 CMS they had way better performance with 6.2 than NEOS... but this has probably already changed (?). Would be very interested in your test results...

Comment: Also don't agree about performance. Neos is consistently faster than TYPO3 6.2 in all our projects. Our heaviest project renders in around 70ms with Neos 2.0 beta.